# What is meaning of exception in Visual Studio for C++ code

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, compiler-construction, youtube

I am trying to access uninitialized memory,

```
int *ptr;

// to this and that

*ptr = 8;
return 0;
```

I get following exception,

> Unhandled exception at 0x0041145e in sam2.exe: 0xC0000005: 
>       Access violation writing location 0xcccccccc.

Now I know `0xcccccccc` is value used for uninitialized pointers in Visual C++. But I do not understand meaning of `0x0041145e` and `0xC0000005`.

Just to clarify, I am asking this question because I am trying to make video tutorial on YouTube regarding **Magic Numbers**.

I appreciate your help. 
Thanks.

Comment: 0x0041145e is exception object location.

Comment: `0xC0000005` is Exception code for `Access violation`.

Comment: @Dayalrai When I see code in error look up, it is not defined as error number. Am I getting it wrong?

Comment: @pranitkothari Each bit have a definition. please have a look to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/het71c37.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680552%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: @Dayalrai  +1. Thanks. Cleared my doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`0xC0000005` is the access violation error code. Such illegal operations with pointers result in an access violation so this code will be seen. On the other hand `0x0041145e` isn't a magic number, it's the location of the offending instruction in the executable, and will be different for other programs doing the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a wrong way of using pointer.
    int *ptr;
The above line is telling you that ptr hold a address to a pointer. By default the address stored is some garbage depending on the compiler, by the error you are getting it is safe to assume that the address is 0xcccccccc

0x0041145e, is the the address of the instruction, which is being executed, or this is the instruction on top of the stack.

so your code has not executed. Kindly Modify the code like this.
    int *ptr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *ptr = 8;
    return 0;

Comment: ".. the Stack Pointer Address (The address of the instruction, which you are executing)" -- no. (E)IP is the address of the instruction that throws the error. The stack resides elsewhere and has nothing to do with this.

Comment: +1. But I think sicietyCoding mean same thing, but not articulated properly.

Comment: @Jongware, it is not the Stack Pointer Address, it is the address of the currently executing instruction.